# Errors when running apt-get update?

Tags: 13.04, apt, updates

```
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/deb/dists/raring/Release.gpg  Something wicked happened resolving 'dl.google.com:http' (-11 - System error)

W: Failed to fetch http://packages.medibuntu.org/dists/raring/Release.gpg  Something wicked happened resolving 'packages.medibuntu.org:http' (-11 - System error)

W: Failed to fetch http://repository.spotify.com/dists/raring/non-free/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://repository.spotify.com/dists/raring/non-free/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/deb/dists/raring/non-free/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 173.194.46.69 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/deb/dists/raring/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 173.194.46.69 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/deb/dists/raring/non-free/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 173.194.46.69 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/deb/dists/raring/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 173.194.46.69 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/amith/ubuntutools/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/amith/ubuntutools/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old`
```

How can I fix this? It happens every time i run sudo apt-get update?

Comment: Looks like some of the respositories you're using aren't available at the URLs you configured anymore. Maybe they're still available under a different URL or they're not available anymore. For further information, see the answers to the question that @karel linked in the comment above.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most of your PPA are outdated or doesn't exist anymore. For example the last one "http://ppa.launchpad.net/amith/ubuntutools/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-i386/Packages" should be replaced with "http://ppa.launchpad.net/amith/ubuntutools/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-i386/Packages".

Look at your `/etc/sources.list` (or the files in `/etc/sources.list.d`) and remove or fix those lines that cause the error.

UPDATE:

The answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-a-ppa) should help.

Comment: Note that some of this is problems with non-PPAs.

Comment: Correction: **raring** (13.04) replaces **quantal** (12.10), not the other way around.

Comment: Also medibuntu is no more you should add https://www.videolan.org/developers/libdvdcss.html to get DVD read capabilities

Comment: `sources.list` may also be in `/etc/apt` depending on your version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

This is a non-standard configuration, and you attempting to get updates (for Ubuntu) from **dl.google.com** (the Google download servers).

Why are you using this setup?

---

*This is likely a temporary condition, but you need to be asking Google (forums) how to resolve.*